# Edit Snipe command sending more than one embed instead of just one

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
const editedMessages = new Discord.Collection();
client.on("messageUpdate", (oldMessage, newMessage) => {
    if(oldMessage.content === newMessage.content)return
  
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  const args = message.content.trim().split(/\s+/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
  switch (command) {
    case 'y!edit':
      const msg = editedMessages.get(message.channel.id);
      if (!message) return message.reply('There is nothing to snipe');
      const edembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#deffff')
        .setAuthor(newMessage.author.tag, newMessage.author.avatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
        .setDescription(`**Old message:** ${oldMessage.content} \n **New message:** ${newMessage.content}`)
        .setFooter(`ID:  ${newMessage.author.id}`).setTimestamp()
      message.channel.send({ embeds: [edembed] }).catch(err => console.error(err));
      break;  
}
});
  });
client.on('messageUpdate', message => {
  editedMessages.set(message.channel.id, message);
});
```

[image: Every time the command is used, it sends the previous ones too]

I want it to send only one embed when the command is used repeatedly. As you can see in the screenshot provided, every time the command was used it sent the previous embeds too. I've been stuck on this command line for ages.

Comment: Do you have any other bot instances running? If you do then thats your problem. Also why do you have two message updates? You should just transfer the code from the second one into the first one.

Comment: Hello! Sorry for the late response. I'm only running one bot instance. This is the only command that sends the embeds while adding on to existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you are forgetting to close your preexisting bot connections.

Comment: When I just said that- 
lol.